# Python Socket Error Handling

Tags: python

I'm trying to write socket error handling (exactly err 111 - Connection Refused) but nothing is happening. Terminal print that Errno 111 occured but it's not doing anything with it:

```
import errno
try:
    #do something
except socket.error, v:
    errorcode=v[0]
    if errorcode==errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        print "Connection Refused"
    else:
        print("Running Application")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Test.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       s.connect((IP, PORT))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Nothing else printed :/
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing `v`. Try debugging `v` or print `v` to the console, maybe `v[0]` is not the error code.

Comment: There is a conceptual error too: printing an error message does not "handle" the exception in any meaningful sense (although too many tutorials think it does). Whatever code called `connect` is going to want a socket and so all printing an error message does is push the exception to the caller when it tries to use the socket and has None. Now you've managed to swallow the exception, moved the fatal exception to somewhere else in the code, and handled nothing.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please show a complete example we can actually run to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use v.args[0] to get the error code.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you index the exception object or its `args` attribute. Better would be accessing the `errno` attribute and give the object a more meaningful name than `v`.